# Weird e-mails in my firebase project authenticated accounts

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an application that I am building with firebase and enabled Google Authentication, only me and a friend accessed the application's .apk, but recently some weird Google email accounts started to register with the application, which neither me nor my friend created it (probably bots as you can see).
Is it possible that some Google API keys for our project were leaked so that someone is creating accounts or something?
Note: we use a private github repository

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens basically when you submit an app version to Google Play for Review. The automated review system will create those accounts to generate test reports

Comment: Maybe related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63914762/827047

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Authentication APIs are actually public.  Anyone can access them, even outside your app.  If you have email/password auth enabled, it means anyone can sign up new email/password accounts simply by knowing the name of your project.

If you suspect this is abusive behavior, I suggest [contacting Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) right away.  This is not the first time I've heard of this happening.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the weird thing is that all the spam-like (about 70) accounts were created with Google Sign In method, not with email/password auth, that's why I thought some sensitive key (Google Auth for example)  has been exposed

Comment: All the APIs are public. The caller just has to provide credentials from the authentication provider.