# Some users get authenticated but not storing the data in firestore for my flutter app

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, firebase-security

I have an app where the users should be authenticated by google oauth first to enter the application. once authenticated the user data will be automatically created in the firestore. The problem is I can see in my firebase console in authentication tab that many new users getting authenticated but only some users data is being stored in firestore. I don't know why. Below is my firebase security rule.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null; 
    }
  }
}
```

```
class GoogleSignInProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  GoogleSignInAccount? _user;

  GoogleSignInAccount get user => _user!;

  Future googleLogin() async {
    try {
      final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      if (googleUser == null) return;
      _user = googleUser;

      final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

      final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );

      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(e.toString());
      }
    }
  }

  Future logout() async {
    await googleSignIn.disconnect();
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }




}
```

Above is how i authenticate

```
Future<void> checkUser() async {

final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .where('gmail', isEqualTo: user.email);
var querySnapshots = await collection.get();

if (querySnapshots.docs.isEmpty) {

  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
  final createUser = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc();
  final firstToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
  final userInformation = {
    'id': createUser.id,
    'name': user.displayName,
    'gmail': user.email,
    'token': firstToken
  };

  await createUser.set(userInformation);
} else {

   // if user already exists I will update here
}
}
```

Above is how I check the user if already exists or not and I will create the user in firestore. The checkUser() function is in a future builder

```
class Switcher extends StatelessWidget {
  const Switcher({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {

            return const HomeScreen();
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Center(
              child: Text('Something Went Wrong'),
            );
          } else {
            return const ContinuePage();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Above is how i check the auth state and navigate user to homescreen page where the checkUser function is there.

The code works fine for some users but for some users it is not working that's why I have no clue what is wrong.

I tried to look for answers but I didn't get any.

Comment: Please show the [minimal **code** that any of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have updated the question with minimal code. Kindly help me to solve the problem

Comment: @Ini add one `print(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser)` statement at the start of the `checkUser()` function to make sure the timing of the calling `checkUser()` is before authentication or after as your users are not able to write data to the firestore db because of may be `request.auth` is `null` if that's the case

Comment: @RohitKharche I checked using print statement it works as intended. I changed the firebase security rule into this  `allow read, write;` from this  `allow read, write: if request.auth != null;` now it works fine, so I think the problem lies in security rule but the security rule I gave is not secure. What shall I do?

Comment: @Ini can you try the following rules : ```match /users/{userEmail} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.email == userEmail;
    }```

Comment: Sorry bro for the late reply, I couldn't check unless a new user comes in, that's the reason for late reply. The problem still exists and idk where the error is. I have updated my question. kindly help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi does my posted answer help ? If so then acknowledge, if not then we can solve it further.

Comment: Hey bro, as my app is already in the production it is difficult to change the document id. I have done some changes and waiting for new users to come in to check it. Thanks for helping. I will let you know if any further help is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I found out that there was no problem in the code. Those users who were not able to create the firestore document had one common thing, an email with a pattern like this [randomName].[randomNumber]@gmail.com. This is nothing but the  firebase generated emails to test our app. Usually happens when you submit your app in play store.

Check out this below question to know about this in detail

[Weird e-mails in my firebase project authenticated accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62273459/weird-e-mails-in-my-firebase-project-authenticated-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking user present or not with query you can also check with the following document exist or not approach where each document id is `user.email` of the users, Although you can also use their `user.uid` too :

```js
Future<void> checkUser() async {
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
  var userDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.email);

  var userDocSnapshot = await userDocRef.get();
  if (!userDocSnapshot.exists) {
    // create new user in Firestore
    final createUser = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.email);
    final firstToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    final userInformation = {
      'id': createUser.id,
      'name': user.displayName,
      'gmail': user.email,
      'token': firstToken
    };

    await createUser.set(userInformation);
  } else {
    // update existing user in Firestore
    await userDocRef.update({
      'name': user.displayName,
      'token': await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken()
    });
  }
}
```

Also check the timing when the `checkUser()` function is being called. As if called before the user logged in it will give `user` as `null`.

Now talking about security rules make sure you provide as follows :

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /users/{userEmail} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.email == userEmail;
    }
  }
}
```

As we are creating the document id same as user.email hence the second rule.

Reference : [**DocumentSnapshot**](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#documentsnapshot)